# GitHubにプッシュした後、コミットしたユーザー名(Author情報)はサイト上で確認できるんでしょうか？

Tags: github

▼試したこと
ローカルリポジトリからターミナルで
% git push origin master　を実行し
GitHub上でプッシュしたものが反映されたこと確認

リビジョン番号は見れますが、コミットしたユーザー名(Author情報)の表記が見当たりません。
＞画像添付[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

▼相談
仕様上見れないんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Author と Commiter が異なる場合には、GitHub 上でも両者の情報がコミットログで確認出来ます。

**例:**
https://github.com/ScratchBuild/contrib/commit/c909c075610c76bc3d191d5f4d85a3d2aa0cf02e

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]